# cUrl Problems with uploading files

Tags: c++, windows, curl

Using cUrl ( windows ) and was trying to get an upload function to work. However, it just doesnt seem to work. Getting error ERROR_FILE_NOT_PROVIDED from anonfiles

Here is the API = https://anonfiles.com/docs/api
Here is my code:

```
std::string UploadPicture()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.anonfiles.com/upload");

        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "cache-control: no-cache");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "file=test.ini");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        return readBuffer;
    }
    return "Failed";
}
```

Any help is welcome. I have tried many other ways as well, but didnt manage to get it right.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: getting ERROR_FILE_NOT_PROVIDED

Comment: should not the file to be uploaded opened before the call the upload it? maybe that's why it says file is not provided. If `test.ini` is the file to be uploaded then it should be opened before uploading using C++ file handling calls like [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/).

Comment: i will check it out